How to select an option in MUI Select using Vitest
I have a select with options defined as below:
<Select 
    labelId="select1"
    data-testid="select1"
    label="select 1"
    name="select 1"
    multiple={true}
   >
      <MenuItem data-testid={`select1_option`} key="select1_1`} value="1">Option 1</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem data-testid={`select1_option`} key="select1_2`} value="2">Option 2</MenuItem>
</Select>

I am getting the select element with (can't get it by role as element has no name):
const filter1 = await screen.getByTestId('select1');
user.click(filter1);

But I can't then access the options to select them. I have tried
userEvent.selectOptions(filter1, '1');
fireEvent.change(filter1, { target: { value: "1" } })
const options = screen.getAllByTestId("select1_option")

But none of these work. What should I do?

Please, can you provide a minimal reproducible example in Codesandbox or some other place?
